# I have issue with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am new to bootstrap and i have been designing a taxi website . I have a issue with it where the whole container of the website is more towards the right side of the screen , its not in the center of the screen.
I guess the problem may be with jumbotron . The size of the backgroud image is
1400x562 . how can i fix it?

Preview of the website(http://threeguys.us/works/employee.html)

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="jumbotron">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo/logo.png" width="250px" height="70px"></a>
            </div>

            <div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/navigation_hover/home.png" width="100px" height="70px"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="rates.html"><img src="images/navigation/rates.png" width="100px" height="70px"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="employee.html"><img src="images/navigation/employee.png" width="140px" height="70px"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact_us.html"><img src="images/navigation/contact.png" width="140px" height="70px"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="call_button">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">call us</button>
    </div>
</div><!--jumbotron end-->
</div><!--container end-->
```

**style.css**

```
 .jumbotron
 {
   background: url(images/car/car.png) no-repeat ;
   background-size: 100%;
   height: 562px;
   width: 1400px;
   padding-top: 0px;
  }
  .navbar {
     /* height: 70px; */
     background-color: transparent;
     border:0px;
    }
     .navbar-brand {
     padding-top: 15px;

     }
```

Comment: Where are your `div.row` and your `div[class^=col-]`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the jumbotron background image? Are you trying to make that take up the full width of the page? The max-width of the container is 1170px, so setting the jumbotron to 1400 does make it break out of the container.

Comment: @StephanieKendall I resized the image below 1170 and its fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options:

1. Place the class='jumbotron' outside the class='container';
   The class='container' has a specific width (1170px) by default. 
   so you want your structure to be:

   ```
           <div class='jumbotron'>content here</div>
           <div class='container'>content here</div>
   ```

OR

2. Adjust the width of the 'container' class. Try 75%. I would recommend doing this outside bootstrap or even inline on the tag like:

   ```
          <div class='container' style='width:75% !important'>
   ```

Hope this helps.